# Add sum of numbers except certain digit / python

Tags: python

New to using python. Was wondering how can I create a function to get the sum of numbers before a certain number in a list using `while` loop. For example, I want to get the sum of all numbers before the number 3 pops up in the list [1,2,5,2,3,2] should result in 10. Using my faulty code, my function doesn't consider the 3 and just adds all the numbers.

```
def nothree(nt):
    while nt != 3: 
        list_sum = sum(nt)
        return list_sum
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def nothree(nt):
  i = 0
  sum = 0
  while nt[i]: 
    if nt[i] is 3:
       break
    sum += nt[i]
    i += 1
  return sum
```

this is so you can keep the while loop for whatever reason. But also in python you could something like:

```
def nothree(nt):
  for i in nt[:-2]: 
     sum += [i]
  return list_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) for this pattern:

```
from itertools import takewhile
def nothree(nt):
    return sum(takewhile(lambda x: x != 3, nt))

>>> nothree([1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1])
10
```

While Fejs has you covered with an instructive loop-based solution, I might add this one-line hack that works without any libraries:

```
return sum(x if x != 3 else next(iter([])) for x in nt)
```

where the `StopIteration` raised by `next(iter([]))` will stop the generator on the first `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def nothree(nt):
    sum = 0
    for n in nt:
        if n == 3:
            break
        sum += n
    return sum
```

If there is 3 in list, it will break the loop and return sum of numbers before 3 was reached. If there is no 3 in list, the sum will be sum of the list. And finally, if there is no numbers in list, sum will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one line as well

```
nt = [1,2,5,2,3,2]
x = sum(nt[:nt.index(3)])
```

`nt[:nt.index(3)]` will give you the list before `3` appears for the first time in the list. ie. `[1, 2, 5, 2]`

Comment: While this is concise, it iterates three times, once to find the index, once to build the slice and once to take the sum. And it does't work at all if there's no `3`.